# Make Xcode's Document Items list always visible

Tags: xcode

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> is used to show this list of class and method names in the current file

[image]

#### Is there a way I can make the full list always visible somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The **Document Items** list should always be at the top of each document. I don't think it ever goes away.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a list in your image. That's my problem. I want to see the full list always

Comment: In my list (for example)... click on where it says **[M] -didReceiveMemoryWarning**.

Comment: I don't want to click and see. I want to see that list while I'm coding.

Comment: It's not something that will persist. So when you want to see it you will have to click on it or use the key commands. What you are asking for (the list to NEVER go away) is simply not possible.